# The corrollary of the pinching theorem

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

J.C Bourin has established the pinching theorem. The theroem is as following:
Let $A\in B(H)$ be an operator with $\Bbb D \subset W_e(A)$,where $\Bbb D$ is the open unit disc, $W_e(A)$ is the essential numerical range of $A$ and let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of operators such that $\sup_n||X_n||<1$. Then we have a pinching

$P(A)=\oplus_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$.

There is one corollary.

**Cor**:Let $A$ be an operator with $\Bbb D \subset W_e(A)$.For any contraction $X$, there is a sequence $\{U_n\}$ of unitary operators such that $U_n^{*}AU_n\rightarrow X$ in the  weak operator topology.

How to construct the sequence of unitary operators?

According to the pinching thereom, there exists a standard decomposition of $H$ for which $A=(A_{i,j})$ with diagonal blocks $A_{i,i}\cong X_i $ for all $i$, where $A_{i,i}\cong X_i $ means that $A_{i,i}$ is unitarily equivalent to $X_i$. If we let $X_n=X$, we can conclude that $A_{i,i}\cong X$, but how to prove that there is a sequence $\{U_n\}$ of unitary operators such that $U_n^{*}AU_n\rightarrow X$ in the  weak operator topology?

Comment: But the theorem is from J.C. Bourin's paper "compressions and pinchings".

Comment: Umm, all right.

Comment: If there exists an isometry $V$  such that $X=V^*AV$, can we conclude that there is an sequence $\{U_n\}$  of unitary operators such that $U_n^{*}AU_n\rightarrow X$ in WOT topology?

Comment: @Ruy: the theorem is nice precisely because there is no relation between the $X_n$ and $A$. Having the whole disk inside the essential numerical range is huge. This result is no different in flavour from the fact that any contraction is a ucp image of the unilateral shift (or any proper isometry, or any unitary with full spectrum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing $X$ with $\frac n{n+1}X$ you may assume that $\|X\|<1$. By the Theorem, there exists a projection $E$ with $X=EAE$. Now you can use that the unitaries are wot-dense in the unit ball.

Comment: By the theorem, there exists an isomerty $V$ such that $V^*AV=X$. The key proof is that unitaries are wot-dense in the unit ball. Thanks very much!